# Xmlhttp async race condition

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I want to display the number of objects in a XML file i am reading with xmlhttp open. But once it loads, the number is wrong, I think it has to do with it being async and it's counting when the XML is not being read yet.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","www.url.com",true);
xmlhttp.onload = function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
       if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
        xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
        xmlDocument=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("toyRepresentation");
        var total_toys = xmlDocument.length

                }
              }
      };
```

The total_toys number count is not coming out correctly, how should I fix this?

Comment: How can you tell it isn't correct? You don't look at it.

Comment: I display it later in the code, total_toys.

Comment: Later where? Please provide a complete test case that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Well, doesnt matter where I display it, the number is wrong.

Comment: Please provide a complete test case that demonstrates the problem.